# What is the difference between landsting and länsstyrelse?

Tags: sweden

In Sweden, there appear to be two parallel national subdivisions with the same boundaries.  For example, see [Länsstyrelsen i Norrbotten](http://www.lansstyrelsen.se/Norrbotten/Sv/Pages/default.aspx) and [Norrbottens läns landsting](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_Norrbotten).  The same appears in other counties.  What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are indeed two completely different things that only happen to be responsible (in different administrative fields) for the same geographical area.

The ***länssstyrelse*** is an agency of the Swedish national government, which also appoints the director (*landshövding*). It is the main representative of the national government in a province (*län*) and coordinates the work of central agencies there, as well as having a number of responsibilities itself. Details can be found (in Swedish) in the ordinance defining the role of the *länsstyrelse*, [SFS 2007:825](https://lagen.nu/2007:825).

The ***landsting***, on the other hand, is a political entity (technically a special type of municipality comprising the area of several regular municipalities; a so-called secondary municipality, *sekundärkommun*). The citizens of a *landsting* elect a regional parliament, *landstingsfullmäktige*, which in turn elects a regional government, *landstingsstyrelse*. The *landsting*’s main areas of responsibility are health care, regional public transport and land use planning.

Sweden has been experimenting with devolution for a while, and in this process, a number of *landsting* have received extended responsibilities. Such a *landsting* is usually called ***region*** (having a *regionfullmäktige* and a *regionstyrelse*).

It is not strictly necessary that a *landsting* coincides geographically with a province, and there have been exceptions in the past. – The province of Gotland only contains a single municipality, which also fulfills the functions of a *landsting* and is called *region Gotland*.